# mysqli() desde localhost hacia servidor web

Tags: php, mysqli, localhost

Muy buenas,

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos en un server web (1and1) desde un php que tengo en localhost.

Nunca antes había necesitado hacerlo desde local host, y por ello no entiendo el error que me devuelve:

[image: error]

Aquí el php de conexion (conex.php):

```html
<?php

function connect(){
 return new mysqli("HOST","USUARIO","CONTRASEÑA","BASE");
}

?>
```

Aquí el index.php:

```html
<?php

include "conex.php";
$con = connect();

if(!$con->set_charset("utf8")){
 die("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8");
}

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM stock_t_38400";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con , $consulta);

?>
```

Si pongo estos archivos en mi server de 1and1 si que funciona la conexion mysqli, pero no llego a comprender por que no entre localhost y web.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Segun puedo observar te estas complicando sin necesidad alguna
en el archivo de conexion puedes simplemente utilizar esto

`<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
?>`

Simplemente crea una variable en la cual asignas el query de conexión y luego desde el index simplemente llamas el archivo y utilizas las variable

```
include 'Conexion.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla(campos) VALUES ('valores_a:guardar')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Como puedes ver simplemente llame la variable del archivo conexión y la concatene

Comment: Buenas, los archivos me funcionan en el servidor web de 1and1, pero necesito que funcione en localhost por que controlan una impresora de tickets. Creo que no me he explicado bien; desde localhost quiero conectarme a la base de datos mysqli que está en el servidor de 1and1